# MapsForge AndroidSupportUtil

Tags: android, mapsforge

I need to show current location on the mapsforge mapView. MyLocationOverlay class used for this in the example code. But I can't use this code because AndroidSupportUtil can't find

my gradle dependencies:

compile 'org.mapsforge:mapsforge-map-android:0.6.0'

compile 'com.caverock:androidsvg:1.2.2-beta-1'

What I should to do for get AndroidSupportUtil, or I need to use some other variant for show current location?

Answer (score 0):

If this is still relevant: You set your gradle dependencies were set correctly. Did you also include a reference to the location of the repositories? Put both into your build.gradle file.

```
repositories {
  jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.mapsforge:mapsforge-map-android:0.6.0'
    compile 'com.caverock:androidsvg:1.2.2-beta-1'
}
```